# Merge two columns in a spark dataset using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I would like to merge two columns in a apache spark dataset.
I tried the following but it did not work, can anyone suggest a solution?

```
        Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().json("src/test/resources/DataSets/DataSet.json");
        Dataset<Row> df1Map = df1.select(functions.array("beginTime", "endTime"));
    df1Map.show();
```

The input DataSet.json is as follows:

```
{"IPsrc":"abc", "IPdst":"def", "beginTime": 1, "endTime":1}
{"IPsrc":"def", "IPdst":"abc", "beginTime": 2, "endTime":2}
{"IPsrc":"abc", "IPdst":"def", "beginTime": 3, "endTime":3}
{"IPsrc":"def", "IPdst":"abc", "beginTime": 4, "endTime":4}
```

Please note I am doing this in *JAVA 8*

The above results in an error as follows:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'beginTime': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: beginTime; line: 1, column: 19]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2462)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1621)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:689)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3776)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3721)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726)
at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$class.parse(JsonMethods.scala:20)
at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(JsonMethods.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType$.fromJson(DataType.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.fromJson(DataType.scala)
```

The initial table output of df1.show() is as follows:

```
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
|IPdst|IPsrc|beginTime|endTime|
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
|  def|  abc|        1|      1|
|  abc|  def|        2|      2|
|  def|  abc|        3|      3|
|  abc|  def|        4|      4|
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
```

The schema of df1 is as follows:

```
root
 |-- IPdst: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IPsrc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- beginTime: long (nullable = true)
 |-- endTime: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is not working: You are getting an error or unexpected output? Also please provide the output/error.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal - updated the question with the details

Comment: btw. I am using a *Dataset* not a dataframe, additionally I get the same error using the approach suggested in the answer below for "concat" function

Comment: How do you load df1 dataset ? Can you paste the code ?

Comment: Please look at the updated question for details

Comment: @L.CWI please let me know if you have the answer since I am stuck on this.

Comment: I tried your code with Spark 2.0.2 and it works well. What version of Spark do you use ?

Comment: I am using Spark 2.1.0...

Comment: I tried with Spark 2.1.0 and no problem neither... I really don't see why it is not working for you. I will paste my code in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to concatenate two columns you can do :

```
Dataset<Row> df1Map = df1.select(functions.concat(df1.col("beginTime"), df1.col("endTime")));
df1Map.show();
```

---

EDIT :
I tried with this and it worked :
This is my code :

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .master("local")
            .appName("SO")
            .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().json("src/main/resources/json/Dataset.json");
df1.printSchema();
df1.show();

Dataset<Row> df1Map = df1.select(functions.array("beginTime", "endTime"));
df1Map.show();
```

Comment: Ideally, I want to create an array with both columns. However, I tried your approach and got the following error: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'beginTime': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: beginTime; line: 1, column: 19]

Comment: thanks for your try, I found the error it seems it does not run from within unit tests in intelliJ but works otherwise.

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can retain all the other columns? I want only these two to be merged, but the rest to stay as is, I do not know the schema ahead of time, so I do not know the names of all the columns

Comment: Also how can i rename this new array(beginTime, endTime) column?

Comment: Ok good that you found ! you can do it with `.withColumn()` : `Dataset<Row> df1Map = df1.withColumn("begin_end_time", functions.array("beginTime", "endTime"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Dataset<Row> df1Map = df1.withColumn("begin_end_time", concat(col("beginTime"), lit(" - "), (col("endTime")) );
```